# Size of tool bar very large when input text?

Tags: android

I follow [tutorial](http://www.android4devs.com/2015/01/how-to-make-material-design-sliding-tabs.html) to  make Material **Sliding Tab**, All is working fine.
Problem comes when `EditText` got focused and Started to type text in `EditText` suddenly `ToolBar` will occupy whole screen .

Code **tool_bar.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/ColorPrimary"
    android:elevation="2dp"
    android:theme="@style/Base.ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" />
```

[image]

Comment: What toolbar are you talking about?  I see a keyboard...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your **toolbar.xml** as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/ColorPrimary"
    android:elevation="2dp"
    android:theme="@style/Base.ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" />
```

Comment: Explain why this works, or what you changed from the op's (ahem) original code.

Comment: As we are fixing height of toolbar to size of actionbar

Comment: tks, it has been fixed.

Comment: Help me, some part of toolbar in status bar. [link image](http://i.imgur.com/pNh5OCK.jpg)

Comment: use `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` in your root layout

Comment: Yeah, wonderful, tks again

Comment: @hungdh0x5e welcome pleasure to work with you happy coding :)